# How to generate 3 hues of colours per colour in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, sass, template-literals

I've created a sass function that generates lighter and darker versions of a base colour, like so:

```
$colors: (
  betpawa-green: #107A3D,
  lime-green: #8DC63F,
  yellow: #FBCD00,
);

@mixin color-generator {
  @each $name, $hex in $colors {
    &-#{$name} {
      background-color: $hex;
    }

    &-#{$name}:nth-child(4n+1) {
      background-color: lighten( $hex, 10% );
    }

    &-#{$name}:nth-child(4n+3) {
      background-color: darken( $hex, 10% );
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  @include color-generator;
}
```

Everything works when I have my HTML like so:

```
<div class='box bg-betpawa-green'>1</div>
<div class='box bg-betpawa-green'>2</div>
<div class='box bg-betpawa-green'>3</div>

<br />

<div class='box bg-lime-green'>1</div>
<div class='box bg-lime-green'>2</div>
<div class='box bg-lime-green'>3</div>

<br />

<div class='box bg-yellow'>1</div>
<div class='box bg-yellow'>2</div>
<div class='box bg-yellow'>3</div>
```

But what I am trying to do is generate the HTML from Javascript template literals, and I'm a bit stuck.

I've got a constant of colors:

```
  const colors = [
    'betpawa-green',
    'lime-green',
    'yellow',
  ]
```

I then loop through that array, and do another for loop inside of it to generate 3 divs per colour, like so:

```
  const markup = `
    <ul>
        ${colors.map(color => `<li class='box bg-${color}'>Color</li>`)}
    </ul>
  `;

  // loop through the colours
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { 

    // for each colour, generate 3 div elements
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      console.log(j, 'j')
      document.body.innerHTML = markup;
    }

  }
```

Although it is just generating one div, not 3. How can I fix this?

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/ZdjWXO)

**Note:** If you comment out the Javascript you will see the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want that right?

```
(function() {

  const colors = [
    'betpawa-green',
    'lime-green',
    'yellow',
  ]

  // loop through the colours

  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      document.body.innerHTML += `<div class="box bg-${colors[i]}">${j}</div>`
    }
  }

})();
```